# How to set Swagger page as default landing page for web api 2 project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, swagger, asp.net-web-api-routing, swashbuckle

I am working on a WEB API 2 Project. I am using Swagger documentation.

I am also using ODATA V4.

I want to set my default page of my web api to swagger, How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a redirect, see an example here:
http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/

All I did was create an index.html with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/swagger'" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

With that make sure in Web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

... it should not include this tag.

```
<clear/>
```

Comment: I will add more Content, I am using versioning. So I tried your solution, I created a index.html at the root folder of my webapi, but it does not redirect. Is there anything I am missing out.

Comment: As of now I am getting HTTP error  404.4 Error Code: 0x80070002

Comment: @AkshayBheda Do you have a link to your WebApi?
In your project when you want to see the Swagger documentation what do you do?

Comment: As of  now, I have not deployed it on Azure. I want to see the swagger documentation as the landing page of my web app.

Comment: When you want to see the Swagger documentation what do you do?

Comment: i will give you an example. Suppose my api is : (http://localhost:50000/api/v1/myApi) I want to see the documentation at (http://localhost:50000/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154444/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-akshay-bheda).